# Is there a difference between pec flies on seated pec fly/rear delt fly machines and cable flies?

Tags: chest, machine, isolation

More specifically do they both target the same muscles, and even more specifically do they both equally target the serratus anterior?

Answer (score 2):

They work the same muscles, just with different resistance profiles, in that one may provide greater resistance at the start of the movement, when the muscle is more stretched, while the other may provide greater resistance at the end of the movement, when the muscle is contracted. This will vary between machines, and with the angle from which your cables are pulling.

Neither of these exercises targets the serratus anterior.

Comment: I would add that the cable flies will engage the ancillary muscles a bit more for stabilization (The argument for using dumbbells theory) than the machines will.